# Как решить проблему в cocos2dx?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Установил кокос2д, начал делать игру, но вылетает следующая ошибка в консоли:
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':MyGame'.
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

буду благодарен за помощь по решению проблемы.

Comment: поправка:
полная ошибка:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':MyGame'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error running command, return code: 1.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.